# Enumerate all fields of a model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to enumerate each fields of a model with his information (column name, type...) ?

Article model :
content string
title string

Comment: Sorry found in documentation... http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-columns_hash

Comment: Write it in an answer and accept it as the correct one to help others who might be wondering the same thing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the ActiveRecord helper columns_hash():

```
Article.columns_hash
```